# Can an inverse $f^{-1}$ be defined if $f$ is not bijective?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Let $f : A \to B$ and let  $A_o \subset A$ and $B_o \subset B$. Show that $A_o \subset f^{-1}(f(A_o))$ and equality holds if $f$ injection.

I know that $f[A_0] = B_o \subset B$ for some $B_o$, but if we take some $b \in B_o$, then I don't see why $f^{-1}(b)$ even has to be defined if $f$ is not both surjective and injective (i.e. bijective).

Is this a vacuous proof? As it seems the only condition under which $f^{-1}(b)$ is defined for some $b \in B_o \subset B$ is if $f$ is bijective.

(Becuase if $f$ was surjective but not injective, $f^{-1}$ could possible map one element of $B$ to two/or more elements of $A$, and if $f$ was injective but not surjective, some elements of $B$ would've even be mapped by $f[A]$)

In the case $f$ bijective, we have $f[A] = B$  and $f^{-1}[B] = A$ and thus $f[A_o] = B_o$ therefore $f^{-1}[f[A_o]] = A_o \subset A_o$ trivially. $\square$

Is my understanding incorrect?

Comment: $f^{-1}(b)$ need not be defined, since we have no guarantee that there is exactly _one_ $a$ such that $f(a)=b$. On the other hand, $f^{-1}(B_0)$ is defined for any subset $B_0\subseteq B$, and we have $f^{-1}(B_0)\subseteq A$. It could be empty, it could all of $A$, it could be anything in-between, but it is a well-defined subset in any case.

Comment: @Arthur, so $f^{-1}(B_o)$ is defined for any $B_o \subset of B$ regardless of whether $f$ is injective or surjective? I don't see how that is the case, unless $f^{-1}$ is not the inverse function of $f$.

Comment: There are two different meanings to $f^{-1}$. One cares about elements and is only defined for bijections. The other cares about subsets and is defined for any function. For $f:A \to B$, this second version is defined as $f^{-1}(B_0) = \{a \in A\mid f(a) \in B_0\}$, in other words, $f^{-1}(B_0)$ is the subset $A_0\subseteq A$ such that any $a \in A_0$ is sent into $B_0$, and any $a \notin A_0$ is sent outside $B_0$ by $f$. In order to avoid this confusion some authors do write $f^{-1}[B_0]$ for the second version, but not everyone does.

Answer (score 3):

you are mistaking $f^{-1}$ the inverse function and the inverse image $f^{-1}(B_0)=\{x\in A, f(x) \in B_0\}$

Answer (score 1):

You are right: $f^{-1}(b)$ is not defined if $f$ is not surjective, and can even contain more than one element. Hence, treat $f^{-1}(b)$ as a *set* for the time being, and hence $f^{-1}(f(A))$ also as a *set*. This is in fact the standard definition of $f^{-1}$ : it is to be thought of as a *relation*, not a *function*. However, as a relation, $f^{-1}$ is a function when it is *bijective*, so unless that is the case, *$f^{-1}$ strictly carries sets to sets, not points to points*. Keep this in mind while the proof below unfolds.

Now, to see that $A_0 \subset f^{-1}(f(A_0))$, let $a \in A_0$, then $f(a) \in f(A_0)$. Now, by definition:
$$
f^{-1}(S) = \{x : f(x) \in S\}
$$
Since $f(a) \in f(A_0)$, so taking $S = f(A_0)$ above, we see that $a \in f^{-1}(f(A_0))$. Hence, we see that $A_0 \subset f^{-1}(f(A_0))$.

Now, for the remaining part, let $f$ be injective, and we want to show that $A_0 \supset f^{-1}(f(A_0))$.

For this, let $a \in f^{-1}(f(A_0))$. By what we wrote earlier, $f(a)  \in f(A_0)$.

*However, from here, we cannot conclude that $a \in A_0$!*

To see why, imagine this situation: $a$ is not in $A_0$, but there is some $b \in A_0$ such that $f(a)=f(b)$. Then, since $b \in A_0$, it follows that $f(a) \in f(A_0)$, **although $a$ was never in $A_0$!**

What does injectivity do? Well, it simply prevents $f(a)=f(b)$ unless $a=b$!

So suppose $f$ is injective. Then, from $f(a) \in f(A_0)$, we can only conclude the following: *there is some $b \in A_0$ such that $f(a) = f(b) \in f(A_0)$*. However, injectivity gives $b=a$, hence $a = b \in A_0$. Hence, $A_0 \supset f^{-1}(f(A_0))$. This completes the reverse implication.

Answer (score 0):

Think about relations rather than functions. A function being a special case of a relation. So $f^{-1}$ is just all the pairs in $f$ backwards. The key point is that if $b \in f(A_o)$, then $f(a_o)=b$ for some $a_o \in A_o$, but, the reverse image $f^{-1}(b)$, while it has to contain $a_o$ might contain other stuff that is not even in $A_o$. Hence, while this question is mostly a straightforward matter of bookkeeping the forward and reverse images - it is not entirely trivial.

Answer (score 0):

As some of the others have already said, we need to use the definition of the inverse image of $f$ on a subset of $A$. Using the fact that $f(A_0) = \{f(y): y\in A_0\}$, consider the following:
$$f^{-1}(f(A_0)) = \{x \in A: f(x) \in f(A_0)\} = \{x \in A: \exists y \in A_0: f(x) = f(y)\}$$
Let's think about what this means. We are looking for all the $x \in A$ such that there is some $y \in A_0$ such that their images under $f$ are equal. Well of course $A_0$ is contained in this set, because for every $x \in A_0$ we can find a $y \in A_0$ such that $f(x) =f(y)$, just pick $y=x$ ! Now if $f$ happens to be injective, then for every $x \in A$ there exists only one $y \in A$ such that $f(x) =f(y)$; it can only happen when $y=x$. Thus only for $x \in A_0$ there exists exactly one $y \in A_0$ such that $f(x) = f(y)$, and that's $y=x$. We conclude that when $f$ is injective, $A_0 = f^{-1}(f(A_0))$.